# Fullpage.js - normal scroll для некоторых секций

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня возникла проблема. 
Подключил Fullpage.js, скролл по секциям работает и все хорошо.
Но мне надо сделать так, что бы первая секция скролилась плавно ко 2-й, в 2, 3, 4 - скрол был нормальным, потом 5+ секции плавно скролились опять.

normalScrollElements: '#element2' - не подходит. Както оно "не очень" скролит соседние скролящие секции.
scrollOverflow: true - также не подходит.

Есть возможно еще какие варианты кроме normalScrollElements, scrollOverflow? Спасибо.

Comment: [Это подойдет?](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html)

Comment: Здравствуйте. Это через scrollOverflow, оно не подходит тем что скролл блока идет всеравно в секции высотой 100vh. А нужно что бы 3 секции которые высотой 100vh просто начинали скролиться, как на обычной странице. Как будто когда доскроливает к 2й секции - вырубало fullpage.js потом опять включало где надо (

Comment: Если есть возможность динамически поставить `autoScrolling` и если можно определить какой сейчас блок, то можно попробовать опряделять блок и ставить динамически это свойство.

Comment: Объединить секции 2-4 в одну и добавить её в `normalScrollElements` ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Fullzz/26uo8vbz/22/       вот посмотрите, скролю я 1й экран вниз ко второму - нормально. А потом попробуйте этот 2й вверх скролить. Он не идет плавно вверх а вам нужно прокрутить еще пол экрана. Вот почему не подходит.